# Unable to edit Public Calendar Event

Tags: sharing, event, activities, calendar

One of the user is not able to edit some of the public calendar events.

Here is the error message when the user is trying to edit the event.

> > Insufficient Privileges You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the
> >     owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For
> >     more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.
>
> Click here to return to the previous page.

I looked into this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000113365&language=en_US) but it didn't solved my issue.

Here are few things that I have things that I've checked

1. User has FULL access to public calendar
2. Related object (Event's Related To) has Public Read Write and Grant Using Role Hirearachy is checked
3. User is subordinate of Related TO Owner so written a sharing rule on Related Object which gives Read Write access to all Related TO records in Organization.Also clicked on Recalculate Button once sharing rule is written.
4. User has Modify all permission on Related To Object.
5. User has Edit Events and Edit Tasks Permissions

Also looked into this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=activities_access.htm&language=en_US)

Please let me know if I missed anything

Comment: What is the URL that forms when the user tried to edit the event? Are you sure its not a custom visual force page

Comment: @rao its not a custom visual force page

Comment: Public calendar events are tricky, because once there are other users associated with an event, it's not just calendar access that controls your ability to modify the event.  Verify that if the user creates a public event, but only invites him/herself, can he/she edit the event?  That will tell you whether it's a Calendar permission issue, or a  Public Event issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to give Read/Write permissions on all Contact Object records and that solved the issue.